# How do I find the partial sum of this

Tags: summation

So I have a sum defined below:

$$
\sum_{m=1}^n 2^{-m}
$$

I know the partial sum equals

$$
\frac{1}{2^n}(2^n - 1)\ 
$$

But how do you go from one to the other?

Comment: Do you know anything about geometric series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2^n}.\tag{1}$$
Then 
$$2S=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), by subtraction we obtain
$$S=1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$
(note the massive amount of cancellation). Now we are almost at the desired expression.

Comment: Do you subtract 2S - S? or S - 2S?

Comment: We calculate $2S-S$.

Answer (score 1):

A geometric sequence is a sequence $x_n$ where successive terms are obtained by multiplying the previous term by a fixed number $r$ - i.e. $$x_{n+1} = rx_n$$

For example, in your case we have $$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16},\ldots$$
where we multiply by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get to the next term.

Given a sequence like this, it is possible to derive a simple formula to calculate the sum:

Let's say I want to calculate $$S_n = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = x_1 + rx_1 + ... + r^{n-1}x_1$$

Then $$rS_n = rx_1 + r^2x+1 + \ldots r^{n}x_1$$
And subtracting the two gives $$S_n(1 - r) =x_1 -  r^{n}x_1$$

From here we derive the formula $$S_n = \frac{x_1(1 -  r^{n})}{1-r}$$

In your case, $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, $r = \frac{1}{2}$ and we want $$S_n = \frac{\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}{1-\frac{1}{2}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$
S_{[n]} = \sum_{m=1}^n 2^{-m}.
$$

Then we can write

$$
2 \color{green}{S_{[n]}}
= 2 \underbrace{ \color{blue}{\sum_{m=1}^n 2^{-m}}}_{\displaystyle
     \color{green}{S_{[n]}}}
= \sum_{m=1}^n 2^1 \cdot 2^{-m}
= \sum_{m=1}^n 2^{1-m}
= \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} 2^{-m}
= \color{red}{\underbrace{1}_{m=0}}
     + \underbrace{\color{blue}{\sum_{m=1}^n 2^{-m}}}_{\displaystyle
     \color{green}{S_{[n]}}} \color{red}{- \underbrace{2^{-n}}_{m=n}},
$$

so we obtain

$$
2 S_{[n]} = S_{[n]} + 1 - 2^{-n},
$$

so

$$
S_{[n]} = 1 - 2^{-n}.
$$

Note that

$$
1 - 2^{-n} = 2^{-n} \Big( 2^n - 1 \Big) = \frac{1}{2^n} \Big( 2^n - 1 \Big)
$$

Answer (score -1):

By Taylor series you can find $\forall x : |x|<1$

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$$

And so

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} x^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k - \sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} x^k=(1-x^{m+1})\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k $$

$$=\frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}$$

Comment: I read the word partial in the question.

Comment: 1) This is a simple geometric series.... Taylor expansion is overkill.
2) The OP never asked for the sum to $\infty$

Comment: Taylor expansion is not overkill

Comment: It was badly formatted before but I guess I misread it

Comment: Taylor expansion requires some serious analysis to understand and is extremely heavy machinery for a simple geometric summation.

Comment: I think it's better but I don't mind you disagreeing

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\ ,$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-1\ .$$

You can obtain the first formula as following
$$(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=1-x+x-x^2+x^2-x^3+x^3+\cdots-x^n+x^n-x^{n+1}=1-x^{n+1}$$

Comment: Where does the formula come from? (I know but perhaps the OP would like to understand)

Comment: @user88595: I put the proof of the formula in the answer, I think it's fairly easy to understand...